# How I can Choose only 3 Options RadioButton or Orders in android studio -Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, checkbox, web-applications

I want to choose only 3 RadioButtons from these donuts(Radiogroup), and if you choose more than 3 there will be a Toast Message that says you have to choose only 3. 
And if at click in the button "ORDER NOW" the order will pass data of this 3 donuts order to another page app.

That's is:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything in code?

Comment: Can you share the code you have and what you have tried so far?

Comment: Use radiobutton within radiogroup to achieve your goal

Comment: Well... If you store it on `RadioGroup` you can only choose one item so.. is not a good opcion @Blu

Comment: You should store the radio clicked number on any variable. Then each time you click on a new Radio, you can check the `var` size. `if collection.size >= 3 //do sum`. And don't forget to remove a number if you remove any item.

Comment: @user113428, Have you found any solution?

Comment: yes , array for check-boxes .. ask every checkbox if they checked and add all of them number array value then ask if all this check-boxes size equals 3 to move to other activity  .. else Toast message if is not.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can subscribe to RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener, so this return the id of radioButton clicked.
You can have a Collection, maybe List or maybe Set. In this collection you save the selection, and before save it you validate if has more than 2 or 3 selecteds. So in this case, you show a Dialog, Toast, Snackbar...